# Gravity Forms submit the form data and then redirect to the custom form action URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to submit gravity form, then redirect to the Custom form action URL(redirects to payment gateway) where i want to send the form data.

When the user submits the gravity form submits the necessary data through POST to Custom form action url, Alternatively it should submit the form.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [gform_confirmation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/) filter, it allows you to change the confirmation message or redirect URL for a form.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
    if( $form['id'] == '1' ) {
        $confirmation = array( 'redirect' => 'http://www.website.com' );
    }
    return $confirmation;
}
```

Comment: I tried this one earlier, Form gets submitted but the data should be passed to the custom form action url / redirect your which i use. That data should post to that custom form Action URL which is not happening.

Comment: What about the gform_pre_submission_filter? This filter is executed after form validation, but before any notifications are sent or the entry is stored, allowing you to manipulate the Form Object. https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission_filter/

Comment: I tried all the possibilities, nothing is working. Form should submit to entries and it should redirect to custom form action url with the data which redirects to payment page. I tried with scripts and custom functions nothing works for me. Trying it from past one week. Any working code that would be helpful.